# How to migrate a legacy Spring Boot API, which uses JSON arrays as payload, to Protobuf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Let's assume I have the following proto definition:

```
message Course {
  int32 id = 1;
  string course_name = 2;
}
```

And the following legacy Controller (Spring Boot) that needs to be backwards compatible:

```
@RestController
public class CourseController {
  @Autowired
  CourseRepository courseRepo;

  @RequestMapping("/courses/{id}")
  Course customer(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return courseRepo.getCourse(id);
  }

  @PostMapping("/courses")
  Course post(@RequestBody Course course) {
    courseRepo.add(course);
    return course;
  }

  @PostMapping("/courses-bulk")
  Collection<Course> bulk(@RequestBody List<Course> courses) {
    for (Course c : courses) {
      courseRepo.add(c);
    }
    return courseRepo.getAll();
  }
}
```

In my `Application` class, I am using

```
@Bean
ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
  return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
}
```

Instead of using `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter`, it appears that Spring MVC is falling back to Jackson, which trying to interpret the type as a POJO:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FieldDescriptor]
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it at all possible to deserialize JSON arrays with `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter`?
2. If not, how can I make Jackson work with Protobuf POJOs, so that I can use Jackson as a fallback if `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` can't deserialize a JSON array payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem.

The first thing to understand is that with Protobuf, there appears to be no concept of a collection (or array) as the root of a message. The "root" of a message can only be `message` struct, which in turn can then contain a collection of objects. So I created the following message type:

```
message Courses {
  repeated Course course = 1;
}
```

Protobuf forces a convention here, but sending collections as a field has the benefit of allowing backward and forward compatibility, as opposed having a collection as the root element of a message.

> 1. Is it at all possible to deserialize JSON arrays with ProtobufHttpMessageConverter?

Yes. I was able to use Jackson's `JsonNode` type as a generic type to handle the array case. I split up the following mapping:

```java
@PostMapping("/courses-bulk")
Collection<Course> bulk(@RequestBody List<Course> courses)
```

... into two mappings.

- Any request with `application/json` media type will hit the first mapping (both legacy and non-legacy case)

  - The generic `JsonNode` type is used instead of `List`
  - In the case the root JSON element is an array (legacy case), deserialize every array element by manually calling protobuf's `JsonParser` on each JSON element.
  - If the root JSON element is not an array, we treat the entire message as a `Courses` protobuf message, but encoded as JSON
- Any request with `application/x-protobuf` media type will hit the second mapping be
  automatically be deserialized from byte format into the `Courses` protoc-compiled Java class.

Here is the working code:

```
@RestController
public class CourseController {
  ...

  @PostMapping(value = "/courses-bulk", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
  Object bulk(@RequestBody JsonNode rootNode) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException, JsonProcessingException {
    Courses.Builder coursesBuilder = Courses.newBuilder();
    JsonFormat.Parser parser = JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields();

    // JSON array is legacy case
    if (rootNode.isArray()) {
      // manually parse each JSON array element using Protobuf
      // and create Courses wrapper object
      for (JsonNode item : rootNode) {
        String itemJsonStr = item.toString();
        Course.Builder courseBuilder = Course.newBuilder();
        parser.merge(itemJsonStr, courseBuilder);
        coursesBuilder.addCourse(courseBuilder.build());
      }

      // call other bulk mapping
      Courses result = bulk(coursesBuilder.build());

      // unwrap Courses result object and convert it back to a JSON array
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
      for (Course c : result.getCourseList()) {
        String jsonStr = JsonFormat.printer().print(c);
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonStr);
        arrayNode.add(node);
      }
      return arrayNode;
    } else {
      // if payload is not an array, we can assume that it is a regular
      // protobuf payload, encoded as JSON
      String rootJsonStr = rootNode.toString();
      parser.merge(rootJsonStr, coursesBuilder);
      return bulk(coursesBuilder.build());
    }
  }

  @PostMapping(value = "/courses-bulk", consumes = "application/x-protobuf", produces = "application/x-protobuf")
  Courses bulk(@RequestBody Courses courses) {
    for (Course c : courses.getCourseList()) {
      courseRepo.add(c);
    }
    return Courses.newBuilder().addAllCourse(courseRepo.getAll()).build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is it at all possible to deserialize JSON arrays with ProtobufHttpMessageConverter?

The short answer is yes.  I can't tell you exactly what needs to be done without seeing your entire controller code, since you are using `spring-boot`, then configuring the bean like you did should work.  However, your bean is formed incorrectly.  Try this

```java
 @Bean
public HttpMessageConverter<Message> createProtobuffHttpMessageConverter() {
     return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
}
```

By default, Spring is configured with 10 messageConverters, but `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` is not one of them.  Your code example doesn't tell spring to use the `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` that you created.  By defining it as a superType, Spring will recognize it and add it automatically to the `autoconfiguration`.

> 2. If not, how can I make Jackson work with Protobuf POJOs, so that I can use Jackson as a fallback if ProtobufHttpMessageConverter can't deserialize a JSON array payload?

You shouldn't need to configure Jackson at all since my above method should work. However, if you want/need to, then you can create an ProtobufMapper.

```java
ObjectMapper protobufMapper = new ProtobufMapper();
```

You can also replace the existing spring implementation of `ObjectMapper` by configuring the bean to return a `ProtobufMapper` instead of an `ObjectMapper`.  However, this would become global and may break your backwards compatibility.  I'd still give it a shot though.

Comment: Thanks for the response! `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` is not assignable to `HttpMessageConverter<Object>`, so I tried this:
`@Bean
  org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
  }`
but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: My apologies.  It should be a type of Message, not Object.  I've fixed the example

Comment: Hi, thanks! That didn't work either. I think the problem is that if my REST Controller  method method takes a type `List` as an argument, `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` will never support `List`, even if I move it up in priority, unless I write my own MessageConverter. I ended up solving the problem a bit differently, see answer.